# Timestamp YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+00:00

Tags: php, date, iso

**How do I get the "UTC, PST, EST, etc.." name from this time offset?**
You can copy/paste this in any PHP file and it will run.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$time = '2012-01-01T21:15:00+00:00';

echo '<pre>';
echo "<b>Step 1 (Have the date now)</b>\n";
$time = explode('T', $time);
print_r($time);

echo "\n\n<b>Step 2 (Get the offset)</b>\n";
$offset = explode('+', $time[1]);
$time[1] = $offset[0];
print_r($offset);

echo "\n\n";

echo date('l F jS', strtotime($time[0])) . ', at ' . date('g:ia', strtotime($time[1]));

echo "\n\n";
//
// How do I matchup the offset in this list? 
// The values are -18000, -7200
//
$b = timezone_abbreviations_list();
print_r($b);
```

Note: I've also tried using `echo date('c', $time);` but perhaps I have something wrong its giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.1.0+ `echo date('e', $time);` will return the timezone information.